# undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this.webview.goBack()')

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-webview

I'm still new to React-Native and I'm trying to figure out how to access my webview in order to trigger the goBack function on it when a user hits the back button on an Android device. Here's what I got

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}   

componentDidMount() {
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backHandler);
    this.webview.messagesChannel.on('text', function({...})) //this is working
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackAndroid.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backHandler);
}

backHandler = () => {
    this.webview.goBack(); //this throws and error
    return true;
}

render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.parent}>
          <WebView
            userAgent={"mobileapp"}
            source={{uri: url}} style={styles.fullScreen}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            ref={this._refWebView}
          />
      </View>
    );
}

_refWebView = (webview) => {
    this.webview = webview;
}
```

And I get the following error on the simulator

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this.webview.goBack()')

What's the proper way to access this.webview?

Thanks!

Comment: The error tells you that `this.webview.goBack` is not a function, so it's not that you're having trouble with `this.webview`, it's that what `this.webview` refers to doesn't have a `goBack` method. Are you sure it's meant to? Can you point to documentation saying it does? I don't do React Native so I may not be looking in the right place, but [I don't see it here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html).

Comment: I tried to follow this tutorial here https://github.com/defining-technology/react-native-backbutton/blob/master/index.android.js but I'm not sure if I'm doing it the right way, in this example there is a button, but I want the back button to be binded to the back function of the webview so I'm not sure if it's possible to do

Comment: Skimming, that tutorial seems to expect a `goBack` method on the web view. But it also uses "traditional" ref syntax rather than the newer callback form, and it's over a year old, and the old "live" link is broken (replaced by that github repo). Maybe WebView has changed? Anyway, good luck with it!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is too late. Found this question when I'm struggling to find a solution for back button on Webview and implemented a good solution by combining few guides / references as below and pretty happy with it. Thought I should share for anyone who is looking to implement a custom back button behaviour in future.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, WebView, View, BackHandler } from 'react-native';

export default class WebScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = () => {
    return {
      header: null,
    }
  };

  _didFocusSubscription;
  _willBlurSubscription;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { canGoBack: false };
    this._didFocusSubscription = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', payload =>
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', payload =>
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onBackButtonPressAndroid));
  }

  onBackButtonPressAndroid = () => {
    if (this.state.canGoBack) {
      this.webview.goBack();
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._didFocusSubscription && this._didFocusSubscription.remove();
    this._willBlurSubscription && this._willBlurSubscription.remove();
  }

  _refWebView = (webview) => {
    this.webview = webview;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ height: 20 }} />
        <WebView
          ref={this._refWebView}
          source={{ uri: 'url' }}
          onError={console.error.bind(console, 'error')}
          bounces={false}
          onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={() => true}
          javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
          startInLoadingState={true}
          onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this)}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

  onNavigationStateChange(navState) {
    this.setState({
      canGoBack: navState.canGoBack
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did nothing wrong to access WebView's ref.

There is something wrong with ref callback on WebView. 
It is called multiple times and sometimes with ref = null so it may overwrite your previously set reference `this.webview`.

To fix (*this is not supposed to happen in fact...*) **ensure** you get a **defined WebView ref** before setting it:

```
_refWebView = (webview) => {
    if (!webview) {
      return;
    }
    this.webview = webview;
}
```